# LTSpice + OPA192 and MMBT2907AL

Tags: simulation, ltspice

How can I add these two components (OPA192IDBVR and MMBT2907AL) to LTSpice?
If someone can help with step by step tutorial I would really appreciate. I tried googling, but most of them suggesting importing and converting PSpice models to LTSpice and it looks like that was doable before, but not now, or I'm not doing something properly...

Comment: This kind of question is not really all that well suited to this site, but here is a video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zUtJ0XWpaQ

Answer (score 1):

Some PSpice models won't import into LTSpice, and those that do aren't always accurate. Before going through the hassle of finding out you should look for   equivalents that might already be in LTSpice.

You can ignore package type, and often the same part is made by several manufacturers who use their own prefixes.

MMBT2907 is the same as 2N2907.

OPA192 is a precision rail-to-rail CMOS op amp with Gain Bandwidth Product of 10MHz. Depending on the circuit you are attempting to simulate, a variety of Linear technology op amps may be near enough to equivalent. LTSpice is provided for free because they want you to use their parts, so why not take a look at them?

Remember that models are just that - they don't mimic *all* the characteristics of the physical part. But for many simulations they don't have to. Therefore you can often get away with using a different part without invalidating the results, so long as the essential parameters are close enough.

Comment: Nitpicking but, actually, package type can lead (pun intended) to a different behaviour of the part. Reason: having more or less stray inductance associated with the leads. All that said, a different package model is better than no model at all.

Comment: @SredniVashtar  LTSpice standard bipolar transistor model doesn't include any inductance  http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=Q_Bipolar_transistor  - and that's not the only thing not included in many models. LTSpice thinks a 2n2907 can handle Vce = 10Kv no problem!

Comment: @BruceAbbott Junction breakdown is typically not modeled as I understand it- it screws up the convergence and normally you don't want to be doing that (allowing the junction to break down)

Answer (score 0):

I might have to chew you out for not doing research. Nah, I'll just post the link: http://www.linear.com/solutions/4678

Quote:

> It is possible in LTspice IV to create a new symbol from scratch for a
>   third-party model but who has the time? Follow these easy steps to
>   generate a new symbol for a third-party model defined in a subcircuit
>   (.SUBCKT statement).
>
> 1. Open the netlist file that contains the subcircuit definitions in LTspice (File > Open or drag file into LTspice)
> 2. Right-click the line containing the name of the subcircuit, and select Create Symbol:
> 3. Edit the symbol if needed and save.